# calling jsp page from servlet class didn't work?

Tags: java, servlets

i'm trying to view a jsp page from my servlet class the problem is that Produit.jsp has worked normally while it didn't work for the SaisieProduit.jsp (so it wasn't a problem of web.xml),also when when i run SaisieProduit.jsp without passing by the servlet class it worked normally.

here is my servlet class

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path=req.getServletPath();

        if(path.equals("/index.do")){
            req.getRequestDispatcher("produits.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
        else if(path.equals("/chercher.do")){
            String motCle=req.getParameter("motCle");

            ProduitModel model=new ProduitModel();
            model.setMotCle(motCle);            
            List<Produit> produits=new ArrayList<Produit>();
             produits=metier.produitsParMC(motCle);
            model.setProduits(produits);
            req.setAttribute("model", model);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("produits.jsp").forward(req, resp);

        }

        else if(path.equals("/saisie.do")){
            req.getRequestDispatcher("SaisieProduit.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }



    }

}
```

here is the link of saisie.do

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="index.do">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="saisie.do">Saisie</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

[here the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzurf.png)

when i click on saisie a blanket page appears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr8By.png)

Comment: can you post your `web.xml` ?

Comment: @guleryuz the error is not due to the web.xml because i have another jsp page that worked normally

Comment: can you only post `Servlet mappings` part of your `web.xml` ?

Comment: <servlet-class>web.ControleurServelet</servlet-class>

Comment: :) do you have `*.do` to `ControleurServelet` mapping in your `web.xml`?

Comment: yap   surely <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

Comment: what it prints when you place `System.out.println(path);` after line `String path=req.getServletPath();` after clicking to "Saisie" link?

Comment: i did as you said String path=req.getServletPath();
  System.out.println(path);   but it still a blanket page

Comment: what do you see in the console/log file when you click the link "Saisie" ?

Comment: unfortunately nothing appears in the console after clicking in Saisie it's weird

Comment: do you see anything in the console when you click "Home" ?

Comment: even when i click "Home" nothing appears in the console, but when i click home all works correctly

Comment: did you re-compiled and re-runned the application after placing `System.out.println(path);` ?

Comment: yep surely but the error still exists